# Personal Best Scorekeeper / Timer

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm making a timer that records the **longest time** (personal best) when clicking 'ok' on the pass button. I can't seem to figure out how to get the counter back to 0 and I'm sure there's a way to do it with only 2 buttons (start + pass). I want the timer to start again when I press start, at the moment it just runs each case once and returns the highest value. The timer currently logs the second after the number shown on screen which I do not understand.

Thanks in advance for your help, much appreciated!

```js
  var c = 0;
 var d = 0;
 var pb;

 function myCounter() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c++;
 }

 function restartCount() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d++;
 }

 function userPass() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
   console.log(c,d);
   clearInterval(myCounter);
   clearInterval(restartCount);
   document.getElementById("personalBest").innerHTML = Math.max(c,d);

  } else {
   document.getElementById("good").innerHTML = "Keep it up!";
  }
 }
```

```html
<h1>Best Time = <span id="personalBest"></span></h1>

<p id="good"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onClick="myCounter = setInterval(myCounter, 1000)">Start counter!</button>
<button onclick="userPass()">Pass</button>
<button onclick="restartCount = setInterval(restartCount, 1000)">Restart</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question "The timer currently logs the second after the number shown on screen which I do not understand."

This is linked to where you put the ++ in this line

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c++;
```

c++ means get the value of c then increment it. I believe you want to increment first (because 1 second has elapse) then assign and use.
In this case you should use ++c instead.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ++c;
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few mistakes

- *timer variable name* and *function variable name* were same, they need to be different. Also, it is cleaner to invoke a simple method rather than starting timer from the `onclick`.
- **No need for second start button**, ensure that you *clear `c` and `timer` before starting new timer*.

```js
var c = 0;
var d = 0;
var myCounter;

function myCounter1() {
  c = 0; //set c to 0;
  clearInterval(myCounter);
  myCounter = setInterval(() => {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c++;
  }, 1000);
}

function userPass() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    d = Math.max(c,d);
    clearInterval(myCounter);
    document.getElementById("personalBest").innerHTML = d;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("good").innerHTML = "Keep it up!";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Best Time = <span id="personalBest"></span></h1>

<p id="good"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onClick="myCounter1()">Start counter!</button>
<button onclick="userPass()">Pass</button>
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! How do I keep the counter going even after I leave the page and have the script keep a record of the highest score, would this be through localStorage? If so, where in the script do I need to place this? Thanks again.